# Should parallel API call use Schedulers.parallel() or Schedulers.boundedElastic()

Tags: kotlin, reactor

To be honest I have no idea how schedulers work in reactor. I have read few of them and this what I found.

> Schedulers.parallel() is good for CPU-intensive but short-lived tasks.
> It can execute N such tasks in parallel (by default N == number of
> CPUs)
>
> Schedulers.elastic() and Schedulers.boundedElastic() are good for more
> long-lived tasks (eg. blocking IO tasks). The elastic one spawns
> threads on-demand without a limit while the recently introduced
> boundedElastic does the same with a ceiling on the number of created
> threads.

So in my API calls there's a task where I have to poll request over and over again until its state is ready.

```
Flux.just(order1, order2)
    .parallel(4)
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .flatMap { order -> createOrder(order) }
    .flatMap { orderId -> 
       pollConfirmOrderStatus(orderId)
          .retryWhen(notReady)
    }
    .collectList()
    .subscribe()
```

As you can see I use Schedulers.parallel() and it works fine, but I'm concerning about blocking CPU usage since my server doesn't have that much CPU cores. The pollConfirmOrderStatus takes about 1-2 minutes so I'm not sure if it would block other process in my server from accessing CPU. So should I use Schedulers.parallel() or Schedulers.bondedElastic() here.

Comment: Is `pollConfirmOrderStatus` blocking or a reactive call?

Comment: I suppose it's reactive call since it's rest api call using webclient maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method `pollConfirmOrderStatus()` doesn't block the parallel Scheduler's threads it should be fine. Otherwise then you might be blocking all the available thread in the parallel Scheduler, which might end up in a deadlock if your state never gets ready.

Here, it explains that parallel scheduler is reserved for non-blocking calls, and that you can use BlockHound to spot blocking calls from non-blocking intended threads.
https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/28/reactor-debugging-experience